# Azure VPN Site-to-Site wite resource manager (Provision Fail)

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-powershell, resourcemanager, azure-resource-manager

When i run the "Get-AzureVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection -Name Connection -ResourceGroupName POC -Debug" cmdlet the Provisionstate is Failed. I have delete the connection serveral times without any success.
Here the results:

```
{
"name": "GWConnection1",
"id": "/subscriptions/ed9cc7cb-a0e4-455c-8a65/resourceGroups/POC/providers/Microsoft.Network/connections/GWConnection1",
"etag": "W/\"e66d8c6f-d4a5-4bb1-80d2\"",
"type": "Microsoft.Network/connections",
"location": "eastus2",
"properties": {
"provisioningState": "Failed",
"resourceGuid": "1d6261cc-6a03-4efe-a492",
"virtualNetworkGateway1": {
"id": "/subscriptions/ed9cc7cb-a0e5-455c/resourceGroups/POC/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/Gateway"
},
"localNetworkGateway2": {
"id": "/subscriptions/ed9cc7cb-a0e4/resourceGroups/POC/providers/Microsoft.Network/localNetworkGateways/PR-Network"
},
"connectionType": "IPsec",
"routingWeight": 10,
"sharedKey": "308201A006092A864886F70D010703A08201913082018D0201003182014930820145020100302D3019311730150603550403130E6E72702D656E6372797074696F6E021072E532F90B53108C4B29C242F8C9C148300D06092A864886F70D010101050004820100089C2DE40C535B5B43E641E5B867618E099169D567CD4BA6",
"connectionStatus": "Unknown",
"ingressBytesTransferred": 0,
"egressBytesTransferred": 0
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question was if someone could tell me what was the problem but i figured out the error.

Answer (score 0):

NVM, I found the problem. I think it was that my local network is 192.168.0.0/24 and the azure network was 192.168.0.0/16 and the subnet was 192.168.1.0/24 and the gateway subnet was 192.168.3.0/24.

Although the local network and subnetworks dont overlap the address space was overlapping.